# Use single static image as map

Tags: mapping, openlayers

I have a single image (a flattened out image of the world map), I want to be able to plot some coordinates in this image without having to create a map server or whatever per se, Idon't know where to begin, whats the easiest approach

Answer (score 2):

This will absolutely position links within a containing div with a background image: 
(inline css used to simplify concept).

```
<div style="width:500px;height:400px;position:relative;background-image:url('image.png')">
    <div style="top:20px;left:35px;position:absolute;">
       <a href="www.google.com">link</a>
    </div>
    <div style="top:120px;left:65px;position:absolute;">
       <a href="www.google.com">link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `OpenLayers.Layer.Image`.